# Botón de eliminar, con alerta de confirmación de Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, funciones, eliminar

Estoy intentando agregar una alerta de confirmación para un botón de eliminación en laravel

```
<form action="{{route('labManagement.lab.delete',$item->id,'delete')}}" method="POST" id='eliminar'>
                                @method('DELETE')
                                        @csrf

                                <button style="padding:0px ;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img/icon/delete.png') }}" class="icon-table">
                                </button>
 </form>
```

este es el codigo de mi boton, le agrego un id="eliminar" para llamar la alerta

este es el codigo javaScript

```
<script>

    $('#eliminar').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        swal({
            title: "¿Estás seguro?",
            text: "Al eliminar esto se borrarán todos los registros.",
            icon: "info",
            buttons: {
                cancel: "Cancelar",
                confirm: "Confirmar",
            },
        });
    });

</script>
```

cuando presiono el boton de eliminar, elimina pero no muestra el mensaje de confirmación, no se que estoy haciendo mal?? help

Comment: Que version de sweetalert utilizas?

Comment: estoy usando esta, https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: pero el problema es q tampoco me toma en cuenta el  e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa por que el submit  lo hace, tienes que mandar el submit en la promesa, y hacerlo desde el click del botón. Solo agrega el evento clic para que al momento de confirmar se mande el formulario

```
 <form action="{{route('labManagement.lab.delete',$item->id,'delete')}}" method="POST" id='eliminar'>
  @method('DELETE')
  @csrf
   <button style="padding:0px ;" type="button" id="deleteItem" class="btn btn-danger ">
         <img src="{{ asset('img/icon/delete.png') }}" class="icon-table">
  </button>
 </form>
```

Ejecutarlo cuando se realiza el clic y si se confirma hace el submit

```
<script>
$('#deleteItem').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
             
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal({
        title: "¿Estás seguro?",
        text: "Al eliminar esto se borrarán todos los registros.",
        icon: "info",
        buttons: {
            cancel: "Cancelar",
            confirm: "Confirmar",
        },
    }).then((willDelete) =>{
      if(willDelete) form.submit();
    });
});
</script>
```